# Trying to get a WPF UserControl to Inherit a Class

Tags: wpf, inheritance, user-controls

I have four UserControls in my WPF Application - e.g.

VisualA, VisualB, VisualC, VisualD

I want each of them need to inherit a generic "Player" Class which contains a heap of shared code -. e.g. methods, timers etc

So far this is what I have tried in my Control's XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="VisualA"
```

And here is what I have in a separate Class file.

```
Partial Public Class VisualA
    Inherits Player
End Class

Public Class Player
    Inherits UserControl
End Class
```

In my Window, I'm referencing the UserControl as normal:

```
<local:VisualA></local:VisualA>
```

But, I'm getting the following error:

> Base class 'System.Windows.Controls.UserControl' specified for class
>   'VisualA' cannot be different from the base class 'Player' of one of
>   its other partial types

What am I doing wrong?

I was also under the impression any code (i.e. methods) inside the inherited class (Player) would be able to access the Controls in the UserControl by referencing by name - is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base class in the XAML is still set to UserControl. Change it to Player. Also note that the namespace for the Player type will have to be defined. i.e:

```
<BaseClasses:Player x:Class="VisualA"
        xmlns:BaseClasses="clr-namespace:MyProject.BaseClasses" 
        ... all your other namespaces used
```

Comment: Hey, I tried playing around with this at one point and hit error like: The tag 'Player' does not exist in XML namespace and The type 'Player' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference. How do I resolve those errors?

Comment: Just fixed it with <local:Player. Thanks!

Comment: You just have to have your namespace right. See edited answer.